# Android - Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have problem with using google anayltics v2 (developing in Android Studio). In manifest I have:

and I have google play services downloaded in SDK manager.
When I try to run my project it says:

**The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 4030500.**

I know it is some issue with GP services version, but I dont know how to fix it. I already have the latest google play services.